# How to access file from /home/runner/XXXXX in GitHub Actions

Tags: python, github-actions

I am currently try to run an action to upload a merged file to onedrive.

I have set up a yml file that try to first clone another private repo in my organisation then which will help perform merging. However, I have store my data in my local machine originally. Hence it lead to action can't access the file.

**What I did:**

I have try to add the data files in my repo repo. Then perform the action. However the error of

```
 for folder in os.listdir(self.dir):
   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/runner/work/Orchestra/Orchestra/data'
```

- My repo is called Orchestra and my data file is called data. Also I have no idea why Orchestra will appears twice.
- I believe the path is called by os.listdir(self.dir) which is a line from my cloned repo.

**What I can't figure out right now:**

- Where does this path come from?
- How can I use my line of clone repo of `os.listdir(self.dir)` to access my data file which is accessible when I run the program locally?
- If it's not possible, any suggestion on how can I access those file ?

Comment: GitHub run your GitHub actions *in* a clone they have made. The clone itself is made using a virtual machine with a virtual file system. For security reasons, you cannot reach out arbitrarily from this VM and VFS. You'll need to be careful about what you try to do within them. Note that this is not a Git issue: it's strictly GitHub, VM, and networking-related.